# d3.js Force-Directed Graph for three tables

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I 'm really new in javascipt, this is the first time that i use it,
I have heard about d3.js and I would realize more specifically Force -Directed Graph
I watched this tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 but for my case I want to link three tables (json), the first contients columns (A up to E ) : 
and column E is the ID of another table , and the D column is the ID of a third table and I would like to see the connection between between the tables.
Can we load the three tables and specify the identifier of each ? how to links between them ? please give me an example of how to do it ? for example : 
first table :

```
[ {
   "COD_T":119436,
   "TERM":"vhf2",
   "TYPE":3198,
   "GRAMMATICAL":null,
   "LANGUAGE":93,
   "ScopeNote":"aaa",

 },
 {
   "COD_T":119437,
   "TERM":"vhf3",
   "TYPE":3198,
   "GRAMMATICAL":null,
   "LANGUAGE":93,
   "ScopeNote":"",

 }]
```

second table :

```
[
 {
   "COD_LANGUAGE":93,
   "INITIAL":"EN",
   "LANGUAGE":"English",

 },
 {
   "COD_LANGUAGE":94,
   "INITIAL":"ES",
   "LANGUAGE":"Espa�ol",
 },
 {
   "COD_LANGUAGE":95,
   "INITIAL":"RT",
   "LANGUAGE":"Reserved terms",
 },
 {
   "COD_LANGUAGE":96,
   "INITIAL":"FR",
   "LANGUAGE":"Fran�ais",

 }
]
```

Comment: show some code, atleast our data set

Comment: I did not code , I just use the example of the tutorial and compiled , as I said I 'm new to javascript and I do not know how to do this,for  my data is confidential I can not show but basically there are three tables the first contains a primary key and 2 foreign key (both primary key of the other two tables)

Comment: just mock an example up on jsfiddle

Comment: I did it in my question above

Comment: you say you have 3 tables, wheres the third ? And how are all these linked ?

Comment: for now I have two tables, the atribut of the first table LANGUAGE  is connected with the second table COD_LANGUAGE

Comment: And the data you have there are all nodes ? So 6 nodes will be shown ? Just to clarify

Comment: yes I want to be shown all the nodes and the link  between them  or show the first one of the table 1 and  when I put the cursor that the data of the second appears

Comment: Theres a lot of work to do here so i will just explain as I cant do it all just yet. Basically you need to create all the nodes from your data in one array.  So an array of nodes. These nodes have to have a unique value. This value is then used to link them. Normally it's an index but you can link them via name, or language in your case. The problem you have though is that you have a pointer to cod_language but no unique value to point from. It would be so much easier if each object in your arrays had a unique ID and a pointer to where it is linked to

Comment: thank you very much for your reply , I can not understand the second part , but I'll try anyway . could you  please give me  an example of code or a tutorial that will help me

Comment: Look here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 thats what you want it to look like

Comment: I can't open the link

Comment: I get : Cannot GET /mbostock/4062045thats

Comment: updated, had a typo